Next.js 14 - Terminal making unending requests very quickly
I'm not sure what's going on here but I'm hoping for a solution. This is very strange and I'm not sure what information to provide aside from a screenshot of what is happening.
I'm building a new website with Next.js, and today when I got to work and ran "npm run dev" the terminal started blowing up with loads of GET and POST requests. Here's a screenshot.

I have no idea what is going on here. Everything regarding this application is running locally. I'm using MAMP to test all the back-end stuff. When I run "npm run dev", as soon as the page is done compiling, the terminal lights up with all this going faster than I can read. I just immediately kill the process and comb through it, but a lot of these things are deep in .next, while some I don't recognize at all.
Steps I've tried to solve this:

Deleting the ".next" folder and having it rebuilt.

Deleting node_modules.

running "npm clear cache --force"


I may reinstall node, but I'm not understanding what is happening. I'm happy to add any relevant information needed, but currently I'm nervous to run the application because I don't understand what's going on here.
Thank you in advance for any help.
Layout.js:
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Header from './components/header/header';
import Sidebar from './(auth)/auth/components/authSidebar/authSidebar';
import { Session } from 'next-auth';
import { getSession, SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import './globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: '***',
  description: '***',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children,
  //Component,
  //pageProps: { ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    //<SessionProvider session={session}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
            <Header className="header" />
            {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    
    //</SessionProvider>
  )
}

page.js:
"use client";

import Calendar from './components/calendar/calendar';
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <main className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row min-h-screen items-start justify-start p-24"> 
        {/* <Image
          src="/work-bg.webp"
          quality="100"
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          className="background-image"
        /> */}
        <div className="mb-32 grid text-center lg:max-w-2xl lg:w-full lg:mb-0 lg:grid-cols-1 lg:text-left" >        
          <a
            href="***"
            className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
              ***{' '}
              <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
                -&gt;
              </span>
            </h2>
            <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
              ***
            </p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="***"
            className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
              ***{' '}
              <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
                -&gt;
              </span>
            </h2>
            <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
              ***
            </p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="***"
            className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
              ***{' '}
              <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
                -&gt;
              </span>
            </h2>
            <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
              ***
            </p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="***"
            className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
              ***{' '}
              <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
                -&gt;
              </span>
            </h2>
            <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
               ***
            </p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="***"
            className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
              ***{' '}
              <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
                -&gt;
              </span>
            </h2>
            <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
              ***
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="ml-72 hidden bg-white rounded-s-2xl grid text-center lg:max-w-2xl lg:w-full lg:mb-0 lg:grid-cols-1 lg:text-left">
          <Calendar />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}


Posted layout.js and page.js at commenter request, replaced any sensitive text with "***"

Can you post an update with your layout.tsx file and the landing page.tsx file?

Updated post - posted on Reddit as well and a commenter suggested I exposed the local environment to the internet and it's a standard web scraper looking for commonly exposed endpoints, which tracks. Middleware is set up already, adding rate limiting now (however if you have any extra insight or think something else is going on I am all ears on this)

Are you sure it's not the way you have the SessionProvider commented out? Have you tried removing it entirely to see if that fixes the issue? If not, nothing else seems like an obvious cause of that issue, unless it's something in the Calendar or Header components.

do you have a middleware.ts file in your project?
